# OpenGL ES 2.0 Scaling not working

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0

I need to scale an object in OpenGL|ES 2.0. Shaders:

```
    private final String vertexShaderCode =
        "uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;" +
        "attribute vec4 vPosition;" +
        "void main() {" +
        //the matrix must be included as a modifier of gl_Position
            "  gl_Position = vPosition * uMVPMatrix;" +
        "}";

    private final String fragmentShaderCode =
        "precision mediump float;" +
                "uniform vec4 vColor;" +
                "void main() {" +                   
                "  gl_FragColor = vColor;" +
                "}";
```

Projection:

```
        Matrix.orthoM(mProjMatrix,0,
              -1.0f,           // Left
               1.0f,           // Right
              -1.0f / ratio,   // Bottom
               1.0f / ratio,   // Top
               0.01f,          // Near
               10000.0f);
```

Drawing setup:

```
    // Set the camera position (View matrix)
    Matrix.setLookAtM(mVMatrix, 0, 0, 0, -3, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

    // Calculate the projection and view transformation
    Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mProjMatrix, 0, mVMatrix, 0);
```

Actual render:

```
    float[] scale = {5f,5f,1f};
    Matrix.scaleM(scale_matrix, 0, scale[0], scale[1], scale[2]);

    Matrix.multiplyMM(r_matrix, 0, scale_matrix, 0, mMVPMatrix, 0);
    // Combine the rotation matrix with the projection and camera view

    // Apply the projection and view transformation
    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, r_matrix, 0);
```

And it will not scale. I can see the triangle and I can rotate it. But scaling does not work.

Comment: Multiplying matrices is not commutative. The easiest way to fix this is to reverse scale and mvpMatrix multiplication but I think this is not the standard way.  
`Matrix.multiplyMM(r_matrix, 0, mMVPMatrix, 0, scale_matrix, 0);`

Comment: Thank you for the info... I have tried swapping them around with no luck. 
How is scaling done in the correct way? Can you point me to a resource?

Comment: The correct order is worldMatrix =scale*rotate*translate so your object won't be disfigured. then after that compute the wvpMatrix=worldMatrix*viewMatrix*projectionMatrix to account for the camera and the perspective. then on the vertex shader you have to do gl_Position = uMVPMatrix*vPosition;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since vectors are column vectors in OpenGL you have to change the order of the matrix multiplication in your vertex shader:

gl_Position = uMVPMatrix*vPosition;

Comment: Thank you, but I have seen and tried this already with no success. I saw it in other answers on OpenGL|ES 2.0 on StackOverflow.

Comment: It is not clear from your code snippets but scale_matrix must also be initialized with the identity matrix. You could also use Matrix.scaleM() on mMVPMatrix directly, but then everything you draw would be scaled that way.

Comment: Thanks that did work, but please explain why I need to set the scale matrix to identity when I don't need to set the rotation matrix to the identity, and give me a proper reference. Thank you.

Comment: When you want to use Matrix.rotateM() then the matrix also must be set to identity! scaleM and rotateM do not create a matrix out of nothing but they just transform the input matrix, which involves multiplication. If you pass an all-zero matrix in, you get an all zero matrix out. Building a transformation matrix by opengl.Matrix class methods must always start with an identity matrix. This might be a starting point: [link](http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/Positioning/Tut06%20Scale.html)

Comment: Thank you, with your help I have managed to get to the place I want to be. Unfortunately your link was not at all helpful regarding specifics of OpenGL|ES2.0, but perhaps I am asking for too much. In the end I did have to swap the gl_Position multiplication, and it turns out I was using **set**RotationM - that is why I did not need to initialize to a Identity. In addition scaleM and translateM perform the operation ON the input Matrix, which makes the code a lot less bulky. In the end, I don't need to use identity matrices or multiplyMM.